# Remove duplicates from inner join with one table

Tags: sql

I have following table

```
id | cId
---------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
```

I need help with query, that return following result

```
id1 | id2 | cId
----------------------
1   | 2   | 1
3   | 4   | 2


SELECT s1.id firstC, s2.id secondC
FROM SingleTable s1 inner join SingleTable s2 on s1.cId = s2.cId
```

But i get duplicates. I want gte result without duplicates.

My result:

```
id1 | id2 | cId
---------------
1   | 1   | 1
2   | 1   | 1
1   | 2   | 1
2   | 2   | 1
3   | 3   | 2
4   | 3   | 2
3   | 4   | 2
4   | 4   | 2
```

Please help.

Comment: Try `select distinct s1.id, ...`

Comment: @Andomar i try distinct...

Comment: Is your goal to get lists of "id" values for each cId, or something else? What you should do depends on what is it that you actually want to achieve. There is more than one way to get that expected output, but the question is what is that query actually supposed to do?

Comment: my goal to get lists of 'id' for each cId, but in my real tabele id and cId is GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just group by the `cId` and then select the highest and lowest `id` for every `cId`

```
SELECT cId, 
       min(id) as id1, 
       max(id) as id2
FROM SingleTable 
GROUP BY cId
```

Comment: In my real table id and cId is guid.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the duplicates (`s1.id = s2.id`) with an extra condition (`s1.id < s2.id`):

```
SELECT s1.id firstC, s2.id secondC
FROM SingleTable s1 INNER JOIN SingleTable s2
                    ON (s1.cId = s2.cId AND s1.id < s2.id)
```

Comment: what condition i need add in query if in my real table id and cId is GUID?